# BigQuery Schema: Repeated Record vs. Record

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, schema, database-schema

I have the following data (sample below), represented by 3 schemas, that I want to store into bq (bigquery).

1. Schema1

   ```
       {
        "id": 1,
        "age": 64,
        "tags": [
           {"FirstName": "Tom"},
           {"LastName": "Hanks"},
           {"Country": "USA"}
        ]
       }
   ```
2. Schema2

   ```
       {
        "id": 1,
        "age": 64,
        "tags": {
           "FirstName": "Tom",
           "LastName": "Hanks",
           "Country": "USA"
        }
       }
   ```
3. Schema3

   ```
       {
        "id": 1,
        "age": 64,
        "tags": [
           {"key": "FirstName", "value": "Tom"},
           {"key": "LastName", "value": "Hanks"},
           {"key": "Country", "value": "USA"}
        ]
       }
   ```

My use case is that I want to be able to group/filter records by these tag values.

1. Schema1 and Schema3 will require UNNEST for any filtering/grouping on a dimension so Schema2 will be the fastest for such queries
2. Storage space is not a concern though it seems Schema2 might be the most efficient, followed by Schema1 and Schema3 respectively
3. Only Schema3 supports incremental updates to the tables with new keys.

My questions are:

1. If we know all the possible keys and define the Schema beforehand, seems Schema2 is the best choice. Would there be a reason to favour Schema1 over Schema2?
2. For dynamic tags, Schema3 seems the best choice?
   Are there alternative schemas, or factors I have not already considered above?

Answer (score 0):

From [BigQuery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#limitations)

> BigQuery does not support maps or dictionaries in JSON, due to
> potential lack of schema information in a pure JSON dictionary. For
> example, to represent a list of products in a cart
> `"products":{"my_product": 40.0, "product2" : 16.5}` is not valid, but `"products":[{"product_name": "my_product", "amount": 40.0}, {"product_name": "product2", "amount": 16.5}]` is valid.

So lack of schema seems to be an important issue in BigQuery. So, answering your questions:

> 1. Would there be a reason to favour Schema1 over Schema2?

*Edit:* You can use schema2 but take care if it is denormalized correctly with "standard" fields.

> 2. For dynamic tags, Schema3 seems the best choice? Are there alternative schemas, or factors I have not already considered above?

Schema3 seems the only solution for dynamic tags.

Comment: I have used Schema2. As I mentioned in question1, the condition is if I know the keys beforehand, in which case tags is of Record type, and this will obviously fail if someone were to try to append records with new keys to this table

Comment: Bigquery allows adding new columns, for record type too, so if before adding a new dynamic tag we can do a check to see if it exists in the schema, and update it if it does not, then it can act as a workaround for adding dynamic tags